# How to get specific column and row value from multiple text files?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have folder "data" with 36 text files. Each file have 3000 more columns and rows. I want to get specific column and row value as a vector

Example, column 10 and row 10. I want looping to get value that column and row on 36 text files in folder "Data". I'm new to R.

Its my code in matlab

```
function data = readImage

data = [];
listImage = ls('*.hdf');

for i = 1:size(listImage,1)
    name = strtrim(listImage(i,:));
    citra = hdfread(name,'PIXEL DATA');
    result = point(citra); 
    data = [data; result];
end

end
```

And

```
function p = point(image)

p = [];

for i = 3941  %column number
    for j = 1595  %row number
        image = citra(i,j);
        p = [image];
    end
end

end
```

I have successfully import files

```
setwd("D:/data")
temp = list.files(pattern="*.txt")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.table(temp[i]))
```

Comment: Please share what you already tried so far.

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: Is your R code successfully import your text files at each iteration? If not, check here for that part of your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/importing-multiple-csv-files-into-r . If you manage to do that then you need a simple loop that iterates over all files and picks the element at position (10,10).

Comment: Thanks you, its work. Now I need a loop to get coulumn and row value each files as vector example at position [10,10]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to grab a specific row and column from a collection of files, I recommend you use `data.table::fread()`.  It is made very simple with the `select` argument. With it you can select the column, coupled with `skip` and `nrow` to grab any number of rows.  Try the following for reading only row 10, column 10 from each file -

```
library(data.table)
datalist <- lapply(temp, fread, select = 10, skip = 9, nrow = 1)
```

If you have a header row in each of those files, you can change to `skip = 10` instead of 9 or add `header = TRUE`.  Then you can name each element with

```
names(datalist) <- paste0("temp", seq_along(datalist))
```

Now you've got a list with named elements that can be accessed with the `$` operator by name.  This is usually better than assigning them all to the global environment.

The list elements in `datalist` will be data tables.  If you need single atomic vector elements then the following may be better -

```
datalist <- lapply(temp, function(x) fread(x, select=10, skip=9, nrow=1)[[1L]])
```

With this you could use `unlist(datalist)` to drop the list to a named atomic vector with all the values, should you not want them in a list.

Another thing to take into consideration is that if you have row names in the file you'll need to compensate for those too.  If you play around with the `select` and `skip` arguments it won't take long to get it right.

For a full example of these methods, we can look at the following.  Here we are grabbing row 3, column 2 from the `iris` dataset, three times.

```
## write iris to a csv file
write.csv(iris, file = "iris.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)

temp <- rep("iris.csv", 3)
datalist <- lapply(temp, function(x) fread(x, select=2, skip=3, nrow=1)[[1L]])
names(datalist) <- paste0("temp", seq_along(datalist))

## results
datalist
# $temp1
# [1] 3.2
#
# $temp2
# [1] 3.2
#
# $temp3
# [1] 3.2
unlist(datalist)
# temp1 temp2 temp3 
#   3.2   3.2   3.2 

## compare to
iris[3, 2]
[1] 3.2
```